# How can I get iOS 7 native UI with mgwt?

Tags: gwt, mgwt

I have a develop a mobile application with mGWT.

On Android works fine but on iOS7 its shows me iOS 6 look and fell.

So, How can I get iOS 7 native UI with mgwt?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK MGWT does not support this theme yet, you could use a theme that's not iOS6 nor iOS7, to get around this problem, otherwise you need to come up with the theme yourself